# What are common resolutions for projectors?

Tags: screen-resolution

I'm looking for a table detailing the distribution of video projector resolutions in a business setting (i.e. not home theater or classroom projectors).

Google brings up a [number](http://www.projectorcentral.com/buyers2.htm) [of](http://www.projectorpeople.com/resources/resolution-guide.asp?resolution=reslist) [resources](http://www.projectorpoint.co.uk/Projector-Resolution.htm) on the available resolutions as a criterion for selecting a projector, but no data on the actual distribution. This is for the design of a tool to be used extensively in this kind of setting.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to why "business settings" would differ from any other type of resolution, in fact I would hazard that resolution is not a business or consumer matter but a requirement consideration for the task at hand. Could you expand your question at all? Here's the display resolution Wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_resolution

Comment: Business setting as opposed to home theater or classroom. These are different categories of projectors.

Comment: Can you provide the links to the Google resources?

Comment: @MichaelLai Yes, see update.

Comment: In the past when questions have been asked about even desktop screen resolutions in business settings there wasn't any good response about what is 'common', so I think it would be even more difficult to get an answer to your question about projectors. However, if the trend with common design is to be adaptive or responsive, how would this information impact on the design of this tool you are talking about?

Comment: We're trying to identify the bottom limit of the responsive design - the lowest supported resolution. And regardless - trends are nice, but it doesn't mean that they can - or should! - be followed in all cases.

Comment: I think the struggle is to categorise a resolution as a "business resolution", something intangible and personal as resolution doesn't lend itself to this. Surely the answer is what suits the users needs rather than an attempt to categorise a resolution.

Comment: I'm not trying to categorize a business resolution. There's a class of projectors [categorized as business](http://www.projectorcentral.com/buyers_guide.cfm). I'm trying to find a distribution of resolutions in that class, that's all.

Comment: ProjectorCentral.com is a great resource as you have found but it has one very annoying UX trait they could easily solve.  You cant search for all projectors with _at least_ a 1280x1024 resolution.  It only returns 1280x1024 projectors.  For years, I thought technology had not gone beyond 1024x768.

Answer (score -1):

According to Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_resolution

**Cinema projection**

- 2K Digital Cinema (2048 × 1080)
- 4K Digital Cinema (4096 × 2160)
- 8K Digital Cinema (8192 × 4608)

---

**Computer monitors projection**

[image: Projection Resolutions]

Comment: Please cite sources.  Using someone else's writing without saying where you got it is plagiarism.  Your post is taken directly from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_resolution.